# Как получить данные в массиве с сервера?

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

Подскажите как получить данные в массиве? Сейчас данные приходят как строка, хочу получать каждый как отдельный объект. С php на вы, поэтому особо его не знаю. Может стоит получать в формате JSON?

test.php

```
<?php
  require_once("db.php");
  $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `dictdb`.`dictwords`');
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
           id: " . $row['id'] . ",
           engWord: " . $row['engwords'] . ",
           rusWord: " . $row['ruswords'] ."
          ";
  }
?>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-test").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/src/php/tests.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
              $(".test-word").html(data);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Если надо в джсоне - получай в джсоне. Хочешь просто строкой, хочешь в xml. Здесь нет единого формата. Все зависит от задачи.

Comment: я же описал задачу. Мне нужно получать данные в объекте.как это сделать? json это предположение

Comment: json - это отличное предположение)

Answer (score 0):

Отправляй ответ в формате JSON, и декодируй с помощью JSON.parse()

Comment: Для отправки JSON формата нужно преобразовать массив в PHP файле функцией json_encode()